# Need to append dictionary values to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have function which returns something like this

```
{a:{b:{c:4}}}
```

and when i again call that function in loop it will return

```
{a:{b:{d:5}}}
```

and again it will return

```
{a:{b:{e:6}}}
```

So i want my final output to be `{a:{b:{c:4, d:5, e:6}}}`

I tried

```
final_output.update(func)
```

But this will update as final_output as `{a:{b:{e:6}}}`

```
    def create_dict(self, make_dict, key, value):
        final_dict = make_dict
        keys = key.split('.')
        latest = keys.pop()
        for key in keys:
            final_dict = final_dict.setdefault(key, {})
        final_dict.setdefault(latest, value)

self.create_dict(status_dict, '{}.{}.{}'.format(name, ton_set.id, ton_id),
                                                  status)
```

Here is my function `func` = `create_dict`.

Will a `defaultdict` help me in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def update_only_new(original_dict, to_add):
    for key in to_add.iterkeys():
        if key not in original_dict:
            original_dict[key] = to_add[key]
        else:
            update_only_new(original_dict[key], to_add[key])

> dct={} 
> d1 = {'a': {'b': {'c': 4}}} 
> d2 = {'a': {'b': {'d': 5}}}    
> d3 = {'a': {'b': {'e': 6}}} 
> update_only_new(dct,d1) 
> print dct 
  {'a': {'b': {'c': 4}}} 
> update_only_new(dct,d2) 
> print dct 
  {'a': {'b': {'c': 4, 'd': 5}}} 
> update_only_new(dct,d3) 
> print dct 
  {'a': {'b': {'c': 4, 'e': 6,'d': 5}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function like this one:

```
def update_dict(my_dict, value, key):
    my_dict[key] = value
    return my_dict

my_dict = {}
my_dict = update_dict(my_dict, 4, 'key')
print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d1={'a': {'b': {'c': 4}}} 
d2={'a': {'b': {'d': 5}}} 
d3={'a': {'b': {'e': 6}}} 
d3['a']['b'].update(dict(d1['a']['b'].items() + d2['a']['b'].items()))

print d3 {'a': {'b': {'c': 4, 'e': 6, 'd': 5}}}
```

Comment: Please Understand my question, Your answer is hard coded